# Dockerfile for mariadb - Container stops running

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I am trying to to build a custom image for Mariadb based on a Debian image, but the problem is that after I run the container it starts running and stops after 1 second.
I want to interact with it using `docker exec -it ...`
but I can't access the container.

This is the Dockerfile. I know this is not complete:

```
**`FROM debian

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install mariadb-server -y

COPY ./conf/50-server.cnf /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d

CMD ["mysqld"]
`**
```

I changed just the bind to 0.0.0.0

I tried a lot of tests and I get any result

Comment: Not sure why use debian.
You can use the mariadb docker image https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb

Comment: i use it as a based image instead of pulling ready made image

Comment: Since you are using MariaDB, this question has nothing to do with MySQL. I edited the tags to remove [tag:mysql].

Answer (score 3):

Is there any special reason to build a mariadb image yourself instead of using the official one from Dockerhub?
The official one provide much better presets, less unneeded software, configurable ENVs and better security.

For your problem:
You can see the output of the container when you build it an run it in interactive terminal mode: `docker build -t my-mariadb. && docker run --rm -it my-mariadb`
On my machine it outputs:

```
mysqld: Please consult the Knowledge Base to find out how to run mysqld as root!
2023-10-19 17:06:22 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

The [docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/running-mysqld-as-root/) say to use the `--user=root` option if you absolutely need to  - which is not recommended.

Also every time the container gets recreated you loose all data. Maybe if you absolutely have to use your own docker image of mariadb you might want top add a volumes line `VOLUME [ "/var/lib/mysql" ]` to your Dockerfile